# Matrix With Data From Related Table

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to develop a Matrix us the data below for a resort with multiple Restaurants.

```
    Cov                         FB Data                                  Location
```

|Check ID| |Covers| |Check ID|| Date       |Locatin ID||Item No||Amount| |Location| |IDName|
1           10       1          7/1/2023      2           a1       10     1          Loc1
2            5       1          7/1/2023      2           a2       15     2          Loc 2
3            7       2          7/2/2023      1           a1       10     3          Loc 3
2          7/2/2023      1           a4       20
3          7/4/2023      3           a3        7.5

Table 1 is linked to table 2 on Check ID and Table 3 ios linke to Table 2 on Location ID.

I trying for a matrix to show Revenue and Covers by Location by taking Location name from Table 3 in rows and Amount from Table 2 in Values. When i add Covers from Table 1 in values the matrix displays total covers 22 for each location. I tried to add a column to table 1 using Related(Location[Name]) and i get an error and says that no relationship exists.
Could you please advise what i am going worng here.
Can't figure out how to load a table in Stackoverfllow.Uploaded the image below
I am a beginner to Power BI.
Hem
Hem

Hi,
I am trying to develop a Matrix us the data below for a resort with multiple Restaurants.

```
    Cov                         FB Data                                  Location
```

|Check ID| |Covers| |Check ID|| Date  |   |Locatin ID||Item No||Amount| |Location| |IDName|
1           10       1          7/1/2023      2           a1       10     1          Loc1
2            5       1          7/1/2023      2           a2       15     2          Loc 2
3            7       2          7/2/2023      1           a1       10     3          Loc 3
2          7/2/2023      1           a4       20
3          7/4/2023      3           a3        7.5

Table 1 is linked to table 2 on Check ID and Table 3 ios linke to Table 2 on Location ID.

I trying for a matrix to show Revenue and Covers by Location by taking Location name from Table 3 in rows and Amount from Table 2 in Values. When i add Covers from Table 1 in values the matrix displays total covers 22 for each location. I tried to add a column to table 1 using Related(Location[Name]) and i get an error and says that no relationship exists.
Could you please advise what i am going worng here.
Can't figure out how to load a table in Stackoverfllow.Uploaded the image below
I am a beginner to Power BI.
Hem
Hem